# Best way to run a Python module in a static website (Pypy, Brigthon)?

Tags: javascript, python, pypy

I'm looking to build a static website (hml/css/j) to run a python interpreter/compiler to import then pytts3 (text to speech) in the user memory. I'm reading the extensive Pypy documentation. If anyone knows if that the right choice? Thanks.

Comment: django or flask

Comment: https://brython.info/ is made for that